# cannot run RoR on Bitnami

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bitnami

I would like to learn Ruby on Rails, and I have found `Bitnami` to Run Ruby on Rails.
But I am stuck, I installed it, PHP scripts run fine, but not the RoR.

I was searching a lot found some tutorials, but i dont know if those tutorials or the documentation is older my folder structure for Bitnami is totally different even the control panel

Could please can someone help me out how i am able to run RoR on Btnami? or could someone offer me something else?

Comment: any errors you're encountering?

Comment: no, no errors, i just placed a RoR project in to the htdocs folder but nothing

Comment: I think you have to run it yourself

Comment: this is the problem what i described lot of resources show how to but my structure is different and im totally new to this

Comment: What do you mean "structure"? How is it different? Have you tried to run `ruby script/server`, and if so, did you receive any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Note that for running RoR BitNami provides [BitNami RubyStack](http://bitnami.com/stack/ruby) (with is different from BitNami LAMP, MAMP or WAMP Stack).